# I am trying to fetch record from empMaster table for the nth highest Salary.But getting error near 'N'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, top-n

I am trying to fetch record from empMaster table for the nth highest Salary.But getting error near  'N' .

```
SELECT TOP 1 salary
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT TOP n salary 
     FROM empMaster
     ORDER BY salary DESC) AS temp
ORDER BY salary
```

Error message is:

> Incorrect syntax near 'n'.

Comment: n have to be realistic number not variable

Answer (score 1):

You can write query in SQL Server as given below:

```
DECLARE @n INT = 5
SELECT salary AS [nthSalary]
FROM
(
SELECT salary, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY salary DESC) AS rownum 
FROM empMaster) AS t
WHERE rownum = @n
```

Comment: Thank you..its working. But can you please tell me what this " INT=5 " indicates?

Comment: I just mentioned n= 5 as an example. You can mention any specific number you want for getting the nth salary.

Comment: if it works, accept the answer. so, it is helpful for others in future.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT TOP 1 Salary
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT TOP N Salary 
     FROM dbo.Employee
     ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS temp
ORDER BY Salary

//* enter No of Highest salary in N Like 'N'=7 ( means 7th Highest salary)
//*Incorrect syntax near 'n'. enter Numeric digit instead of 'n'

Answer (score 0):

`N` will have some numeric value. So, use `TOP (5)` or `TOP (@Nvariable)`.

You can use dense_rank to find highest salary employees :

```
select emp.*
from (select emp.*, 
             dense_rank() over (order by sal desc) as seq
      from empmaster emp
     ) emp
where emp.seq <= 5; -- Pass variable or change Nth value here
```

`Dense_rank()` will give you ties employees, meaning that if one or more employees have same salary then it will give you all.